# Custom post type with custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

My WP site has 2 custom post types, "Projects" and "People". There can be unlimited number of "People" per project and I'm thinking about a way to integrate the projects section with "People" section. My first impression was using custom taxonomies. But the problem is, is there a way to set a relationship between these 2? If custom taxonomy is the only way, is there a way to make it so when adding new people custom taxonomy get created as well?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-types-and-relations?replies=28 Scan through and see if any of this helps? Seems possibly like a solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't stated your requirements of People type and Project type. So I am assuming that you must have both as a post type. To create relations between them you can use @scribu's [Post 2 Post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) relations plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Am using the [zigconnect](http://www.zigpress.com/wordpress/plugins/zigconnect/) plugin on a site where 3 custom post types are related to each other. I got clients, events and products and with this plugin i can do the links within the wp admin very easilly. Here's the [site](http://netbureau.com.br/avbrazil/site/eventos/) in construction for a demo.

Comment: thanks for that plugin, seems its user friendly, but lack of customization options.